# Установка первого дня недели в JDataPicker 1.3.4

Tags: java, swing

имеется код

```
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p=new Properties();
    p.put("text.today","Today");
    p.put("text.month","Month");
    p.put("text.year","Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel=new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker=new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new 
    DateLabelFormatter());
```

Подскажите, каким образом можно установить первым днем недели ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК, метод     datePicker.setFirstDayMonday () я так понял в версии 1.3.4 не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Первый день недели является принадлежность `Locale` - локали компа на котором работает прога, Swing берет эти данные оттуда, например:

```
Locale[] locales = new Locale[]{
    new Locale("ru", "RU"),
    new Locale("en", "US"),
    new Locale("fr", "FR"),
};

for(Locale locale:locales) {
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek);
}
```

Выдаст нечто похожее на:

> Monday
>
> Sunday
>
> Monday

Соответственно, просто поменяйте свою локаль на компе и все.

Comment: Спасибо, но как связать Locate и JDatePickerImpl?

Comment: Вы не поняли. Ничего связывать не надо. `JDatePicker` берет локаль из JVM, а JVM берет ее из ОС, а в ОС нужную локаль устанавливает юзер

Comment: Не помогло первый день воскресение